# php to execute python script failed

Tags: php, python

I want to execute python script in PHP but it does not work, the python script is not running. But when I directly execute the python script using cmd, the script work.
Below is my PHP code.

```
<?php
exec('python C:\wamp64\www\dashbot\mergeCSV.py',$output,$return);

if(!$return)
{
 echo "success!";
}
else
{
echo "failed!";
}
?>
```

Comment: If you want that somebody give you some help, please elaborate better the "does not work".

Comment: can you show us the error msg?

Comment: "_it does not work_" That dreaded error again. What doesn't work?

Comment: which error you are getting?

Comment: Try replacing \ with \\. You might also want to use the complete path to your `python`-executable

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the first line of the python script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

1. Make sure that the python script has the execution permission
   **(+x).**
2. If you are running PHP via Apache, make sure the Apache
   user(www-data) has permission to access & execute the script.
3. Mention the full path to python `exec('full/path/to/python C:\wamp64\www\dashbot\mergeCSV.py',$output,$return);`